# how to SUM certain rows in SQL depending on different status

Tags: sql, sum

how to SUM certain rows in SQL depending on different status where status A should be counted if the same user for the same article doesnt have status B.

| ArticleID | UserID | Status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Art1 | Ana1 | A |
| Art1 | Ana1 | B |
| Art1 | Jon1 | A |
| Art8 | Jon1 | B |
| Art1 | Eve1 | A |
| Art2 | Eve1 | A |
| Art2 | Jos1 | C |
| Art3 | Jos1 | B |
| Art4 | Jos1 | A |
| Art2 | Jos1 | B |
| Art4 | Tin1 | A |
| Art7 | Tin1 | B |
| Art8 | Tin1 | A |
| Art9 | May1 | B |
| Art6 | May1 | A |

for example to SUM all with status A is:
`SUM(case when  status like 'A%' then 1 else 0 end) as Status_A` (this will result 8)

but if I want To count all Status A but only if the same user on same article doesnt have B result  it should give 7 because Ana have both A and B for the same article. So how to achieve that?
Thanks!

I tried

```
SUM(case when  status like 'A%' and status not like 'B%' then 1 else 0 end) 
as Status_A_not_B.
```

i know it can't be done like that but I can't think of any working solution

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms

Answer (score 0):

we need to do some tricks to exclude the repeated mentioned row before counting
you can try something like that

```
SELECT count(*) AS total,
       status
FROM
  (SELECT a.status,
          a.ArticleID,

     (SELECT count(*)
      FROM articles a2
      WHERE a.UserID = a2.UserID
        AND a.ArticleID = a2.ArticleID
        AND a2.status != 'A' ) AS ignored_row
   FROM `articles` a) articles_clean
WHERE articles_clean.ignored_row = 0
  AND status = 'A';
```